# Can I construct an SPL token account by myself and assign this account to Token Program?

Tags: spl-token

Can I make some USDC like magic via the method described as following?

I'll use a keypair to create an account (say account A) with the same space as a token account. Then I'll assign account A to a custom program, and the program will write data to account A. After writing data, now account A just looks like a normal token account.

For example, the token account is defined as following:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Account {
    pub mint: Pubkey,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub delegate: COption<Pubkey>,
    pub state: AccountState,
    pub is_native: COption<u64>,
    pub delegated_amount: u64,
    pub close_authority: COption<Pubkey>,
}
```

My custom program will make account A into this format, with `mint` field equal to USDC's mint, `owner` field equal to my wallet, `amount` field equal to a fairly large number like $1,000,000,000 USDC.

Then, my custom program will assign account A to Token Program. I'm wondering how Token Program can tell the difference between my fake USDC token account and a real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign an account to another program that has data.

Requirements to assign:

- only the owner of the account may change owner
- if the account is writable
- if the account is not executable
- if the data is zero-initialized or empty

You can read up on it here:
https://solana.wiki/zh-cn/docs/account-model/
and here:
https://solana.com/docs/core/runtime

Comment: Could you please share an official link that describes this behavior? This behavior isn't even documented on [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/system_instruction/fn.assign.html)

Comment: I've found it myself. The Solana official doc ([here](https://solana.com/docs/core/runtime)) describes what Solana runtime will check. And it says: Only the owner of the account may change owner. And only if the account is writable. And only if the account is not executable. And only if the data is zero-initialized or empty.

Comment: Thank you i updated the answer and here is some more info: https://solana.wiki/zh-cn/docs/account-model/

Comment: nice idea though ;)